# Combining two scenes with different extents without overlapping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, combine

My AOI is split between two Sentinel-2 scenes. These rasters do not overlap. So function 'merge' in the Raster menu of QGIS cannot help - it says `'Layers do not have common extent'`.

How to combine it to the one, bigger layer?

I tried in R as well, but no functions helped.

Comment: What exactly have you tried in R? Can you provide a piece of the code or an error that you got? IMHO It is also not highly recommended to insert both softwares in one question

Comment: Build a virtual raster

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this in QGIS2.18.24 using two small raster files without overlap, using the default settings for the merge tool, but the tool was running fine (i.e. *gdal_merge.bat -of GTiff -o F:/Desktop/merge.tif F:\Desktop\raster1.tif F:\Desktop\raster2.tif*). The area between the rasters was filled with NoData values.

What version of QGIS are you on and what is the exact error message given?

Comment: Hello, my QGIS is 3.6 Noosa. I guess there gdal tool is deprecated, and now it is a default tool of Raster Menue. I.e. 'Merge'. And it doesnt produce error, it cannot run merging. In the field 'Outputs' of the context menu for merging, just a phrase appears: 'Rasters do not overlap' and I cannot run merging.

Comment: Can you do the merge using QGIS2.18?

Answer (score -1):

I've written a python script solution yesterday. Here it is. Hope it works for you:

https://ourednik.info/maps/2021/05/21/unify-the-extent-of-rasters-in-qgis-3-to-avoid-clipping-in-raster-calculator/

Comment: Do you want to include (essential parts of) this script here in case the link gets outdated?